# Easiest way to convert from string to number in nodejs so i can do $avg

Tags: node.js, mongodb, numbers, type-conversion

What i have is 1000 data of different fields. I realized that i cant get the average in my mongodb if the datas which were imported from excel are string. What is the easiest way to get all my 1000 data to be number.

What i have so far:

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('meibanlist', ['contact']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var async  = require('async');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/meibanlist', function (req, res) {
  console.log('I received a GET request');

  db.meibanlist.find(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});


app.post('/meibanlist', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  db.meibanlist.insert(req.body, function(err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.delete('/meibanlist/', function (req, res) {
  console.log();
  db.meibanlist.remove(function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.get('/meibanlist/', function (req, res) {
  console.log();
  db.meibanlist.findOne(function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.put('/meibanlist/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.machine_Id);
  db.meibanlist.findAndModify({
    query: {_id: mongojs.machine_Id},
    update: {$set: {machine_Id: req.body.machine_Id, air_Temp: req.body.air_Temp, water_Temp: req.body.water_Temp, heat_Temp: req.body.heat_Temp, room_Temp: req.body.room_Temp, date:req.body.date, time: req.body.time}},
    new: true}, function (err, doc) {
      res.json(doc);
    }
  );
});  
  app.get('/convertStringsToNumbe' , function(req, res){
      var recUpdated = 0;
      db.contact.find({}, function(err , meibanlist){
    if(meibanlist.length){
        async.eachSeries(meibanlist , function(listItem , cb){
            if(listItem && typeof listItem.air_Temp == 'string'){
                db.contact.update( 
                   { machine_Id: listItem.machine_Id}, 
                   { $set : { "air_Temp" : parseInt(listItem.air_Temp) } }
                ,function(err , updatedRec){
                    recUpdated++;
                    cb();
                });
            }
            else{
              console.log('already String')
              cb();
            }
        } , function(){
            console.log('operation completed, records updated count = ' + recUpdated);
            return true;
        })
    }   
    else{
        console.log('no data returned');
    }
  })
  });

app.listen(3000);
console.log('3000');
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <title>Meiban App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>Meiban App</h1>

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>machine_Id</th>         
          <th>air_temp</th>
          <th>water_temp</th>        
          <th>heat_temp</th>
          <th>room_temp</th>
          <th>date</th>
          <th>time</th>
          <th>Action</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.machine_Id" ></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.air_temp"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.water_temp"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.heat_temp"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.room_temp"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.time"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.date"></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addContact()">Add Collection</button></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="update()">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="contact in meibanlist">
          <td>{{contact.machine_Id }}</td>
          <td>{{contact.air_temp}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.water_temp}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.heat_temp}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.room_temp}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.date}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.time}}</td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(contact._id)">Remove</button></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="edit(contact._id)">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");


var refresh = function() {
  $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response) {
    console.log("I got the data I requested");
    $scope.contactlist = response;
    $scope.contact = "";
  });
};

refresh();

$scope.addContact = function() {
  console.log($scope.contact);
  $http.post('/contactlist', $scope.contact).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    refresh();
  });
};

$scope.remove = function(id) {
  console.log(id);
  $http.delete('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response) {
    refresh();
  });
};

$scope.edit = function(id) {
  console.log(id);
  $http.get('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response) {
    $scope.contact = response;
  });
};  

$scope.update = function() {
  console.log($scope.contact._id);
  $http.put('/contactlist/' + $scope.contact._id, $scope.contact).success(function(response) {
    refresh();
  });
};

$scope.deselect = function() {
  $scope.contact = "";
};

}]);
```

its giving me this error though:

```
TypeError: db.contact.find(...).then is not a function
   at /home/balkis96/FYP/Meiban/server.js:55:27
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/balkis96/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/home/balkis96/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/home/balkis96/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/balkis96/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at /home/balkis96/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (/home/balkis96/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/home/balkis96/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at jsonParser (/home/balkis96/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:103:7)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/balkis96/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

do npm install async --save

```
  var async  = require('async');

  app.get('/convertStringsToNumbe' , function(req, res){
      var recUpdated = 0;
      db.contact.find({}).then(function(meibanlist){
        if(meibanlist.length){
            async.eachSeries(meibanlist , function(listItem , cb){
                if(listItem && typeof listItem.air_Temp == 'string'){
                    db.contact.update( 
                       { machine_Id: listItem.machine_Id}, 
                       { $set : { "air_Temp" : parseInt(listItem.air_Temp) } }
                    ).then(function(){
                        recUpdated++;
                        cb();
                    });
                }
                else{
                  console.log('already String')
                  cb();
                }
            } , function(){
                console.log('operation completed, records updated count = ' + recUpdated);
                return true;
            })
        }   
        else{
            console.log('no data returned);
        }
      })
  });
```

hit this route using postman or simply in browser

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133751/discussion-on-answer-by-asif-saeed-easiest-way-to-convert-from-string-to-number).